# Can't run session cleanup cron in appengine on non default service

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Java web app running on app engine standard.

It used to run as default service in my project, and I have this cron job to clear the old sessions:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine-java/Tw2a8cYz05o/UgsWaoQhWYcJ

I was following this documentation to split up my monolith web application into micro services:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/microservices-on-app-engine

The frontend & backend were both in the Java web app, but now I am developing a frontend in React.js and run that frontend as the default service in the same app engine project (using the nodejs runtime).

The java web app will now only serve as back end, so I set the service to: `<service>backend</service>`

I use a dispatch.yaml file to point the /static/ path to the frontend and all other paths to the back end.

```
# Rules for dispatch file...
# Put specific cases at the top, other
dispatch:
# Apart from the react frontend on a custom url.
  - url: "blindepoule.appspot.com/static/*"
    service: default
# Route the rest to the backend
  - url: "blindepoule.appspot.com/*"
    service: backend
```

This works great! But the sessioncleanup cron job is now failing:
[image]

It does work directly on the specific service url:
https://backend-dot-blindepoule.appspot.com/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear

But not on:
https://blindepoule.appspot.com/_ah/sessioncleanup?clear

When looking in the log server of the frontend service, it seems that the frontend receives the /_ah/sessioncleanup call and returns a 404. My dispatch.yaml doesn't redirect the call to the backend service.

I wanted to add an explicit reference to the dispatch.yaml, but the documentation says it will ignore and url's starting with "_ah". I also read you can specify a target in the appengine-web.xml file, but you have to enter a version in there. Then I would have to update it every time I update a version (which I do a lot because it's so easy in app engine). I would prefer to specify that the cron job needs to look at the backend service, in my case:
https://backend-dot-blindepoule.appspot.com/

Update: I tried to change the servlet to a path without _ah in it, changed "_ah" to "api".

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>_ah_sessioncleanup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.SessionCleanupServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>_ah_sessioncleanup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/sessioncleanup</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Sessions Removal</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/sessioncleanup</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This works when running locally on the dev server, but on app engine I got a 404 (the logs showed that it got the 404 on the backend service, so it wasn't incorrectly mapped):
https://blindpool.com/api/sessioncleanup?clear
Even on the direct url of the service (what worked before):
https://backend-dot-blindepoule.appspot.com/api/sessioncleanup?clear
Maybe there is a precondition in the com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.SessionCleanupServlet to throw a 404 if it is not coming from a _ah pattern.

I suppose I could write my own servlet that removes records.

Any ideas? My full source: https://github.com/Leejjon/Blindpool

Answer (score 1):

The `_ah/` URL paths are reserved for very specific handlers, the dispatch file rules do not apply to them. From [dispatch.xml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/dispatchref) (the *url* row in the **Syntax** table):

> URL paths that begin with */_ah/* are not routed by the dispatch file.

The fact that it works for you when you use the *-dot-* address is simply because in that case you're using [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing), not [Routing with a dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file)

But with your service now running as a backend - would you still have user session info compatible with that dedicated `_ah`-based library that you need to clean up? I'd imagine the session info is now handled by the frontend react service...

Comment: It will take a while before I will actually start using the react frontend. I hoped to keep the jsp's working until I finish the react frontend.